# Google Cloud SQL: Alternative to LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: load-data-infile, google-cloud-sql

I am working in Google App Engine and we have a Python script that dumps data in Google Cloud SQL. One of the data sets we have to dump is huge. We dump around 150K rows of data once a day daily.

I know Google Cloud SQL does not support `LOAD DATA INFILE`, which I would have normally used. My question is, whether there is an alternative to `LOAD DATA INFILE` that I can use to speed up the process of data dumping.

Inserting the data normally, without `LOAD DATA INFILE`, takes about 5 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by "inserting the data normally"?  Piping through google_sql.sh?

Comment: Currently, I have a Python script that constructs a MySQL INSERT INTO query from the data set and executes it.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in this [comment of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010199/importing-data-to-google-cloud-sql-via-csv#comment40814273_26010199), `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is supported by App Engine.

The [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) explains on how to use this statement.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't mention `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. I think you wanted to link to the comments section of the corresponding question instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's what I wanted. Is there a way to link to comments. That will be preferable

Comment: I think your answer is fine now. However, it is possible to link to comments: You can access the link to a comment by right clicking on the timestamp of that comment. In the context menu then select to copy the link target.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do to get better bulk import performance:

- Create a .sql file and [do an import](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import_export#importing)
- Make sure that the insert statements do more than one row at a time.  A good rule of thumb is one megabyte per INSERT.
- Switch to [async replication](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#replication)
- Do the import from an App Engine app.  The app will be colocated with your Cloud SQL instance, greatly reducing the network latency.