# Google Cloud SQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, load-data-infile

I am running a web server using a google cloud compute engine vm and I am trying to dump a cvs file into the database.  I know `LOAD DATA INFILE` is not supported, however `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is.  How do I use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814775/google-cloud-sql-alternative-to-load-data-infile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814775/google-cloud-sql-alternative-to-load-data-infile), you can use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to accomplish this task.

The command syntax is as follows:

LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]

For more information, please refer to the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).